# MDM push certificate creation

Tags: iphone, push, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I'm interesting in creation of PushCertWebRequest (this is from apple documentation)
I have found a lot of docs how to do this for 3rd party vendors like Air-watch and so on, but they skip last step where they are working with your .p12 certificate. I mean process when you should create PushCertWebRequest and upload it to https://identity.apple.com/pushcert

So my question is how to create a Push Certificate Request plist.
the example of this plist should be following (this is from apple doc)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>PushCertRequestCSR</key>
<string>
MIIDjzCCAncCAQAwDzENMAsGA1UEAwwEdGVzdDCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD
</string>
<key>PushCertCertificateChain</key>
<string>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDkzCCAnugAwIBAgIIQcQgtHQb9wwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwUjEaMBgGA1UE
AwwRU0FDSSBUZXN0IFJvb3QgQ0ExEjAQBgNVBAsMCUFwcGxlIElTVDETMBEGA1UE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDlTCCAn2gAwIBAgIIBInl9fQbaAkwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwXDEkMCIGA1UE
AwwbU0FDSSBUZXN0IEludGVybWVkaWF0ZSBDQSAxMRIwEAYDVQQLDAlBcHBsZSBJ
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDpjCCAo6gAwIBAgIIKRyFYgyyFPgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwXDEkMCIGA1UE
AwwbU0FDSSBUZXN0IEludGVybWVkaWF0ZSBDQSAxMRIwEAYDVQQLDAlBcHBsZSBJ
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDiTCCAnGgAwIBAgIIdv/cjbnBgEgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwUjEaMBgGA1UE
AwwRU0FDSSBUZXN0IFJvb3QgQ0ExEjAQBgNVBAsMCUFwcGxlIElTVDETMBEGA1UE
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</string>
<key>PushCertSignature</key>
<string>
CGt6QWuixaO0PIBc9dr2kJpFBE1BZx2D8L0XH0Mtc/DePGJOjrM2W/IBFY0AVhhEx
</string>
```

Finally I created PushCertRequestCSR and PushCertSignature, but I don't really know how to create PushCertCertificateChain block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [detailed steps and source code here](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) to generate plist.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I ported the softhinker java code to python, and added a few nice things. It's available on GitHub: http://www.github.com/grinich/mdmvendorsign.

Answer (score 0):

- create a CSR using any toolkit, i.e. KeyChain Access on Mac System,
  then export private key as 'vendor.p12'
- log in to Apple Member Center, and go to 'iOS Provisioning Portal'
- select 'Certificates' on the left navigation bar, and click 'Other'
  tab on the center.
- follow the instruction on that page, and upload the CSR you created.
- then the certificate for you as a MDM vendor will be available to
  download on the 'Other' tab. And download it.
- download WWDR intermediate certificate.
- download Apple root certificate.
- execute below openssl command to convert MDM vendor certificate, WWDR
  certificate, and Apple root certificate to PEM format one by one :

  openssl x509 -inform der -in mdm_identity.cer -out mdm.pem

  openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleWWDRCA.cer -out intermediate.pem

  openssl x509 -inform der -in AppleIncRootCertificate.cer -out root.pem
- Then use the attached Java program in the [softthinker](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) webpage to generate encoded plist.
  You need to replace the placeholder in the java package with your own ones because the provided on the java package is just sample one(zero size) which are:

customer.der, vendor.p12, mdm.pem, intermediate.pem, root.pem

- Now first verify the generated plist.xml format that should match with the sample plist.xml provided in MDM Protocol Reference document.
- If plist.xml is in appropriate format then upload the **encoded_plist** to [portal](https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/) . So we need to take care that plist.xml is just for our reference this is not for upload.For upload encoded_plist only.
  After that download the certificate from [portal](https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/).

Comment: People are starting to notice you are linking quite often to softhinker.com.  Pretty soon you'll be racking up the spam flags.  You might want to ease up on that a little.  Perhaps put the link at the end rather than the beginning?  Maybe retire it for a few questions?