# How to be a MDM Vendor for iOS

Tags: ios, mdm

Did a lot of research on this. Saw several opinions, few say I need a Apple Enterprise account, few say I don't. 
Having a MAC server would help? Do I need to have an enterprise account to be a MDM vendor. Any pointers would be great.

I saw the technical business document provided by MDM, but it was not explaining anything about the internal implementation of the server.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Were you able to build something? Have you open sourced it by any chance? I am looking for some samples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After research, we need to have a Enterprise Developer account from Apple, and we need to send MDM payload, from the web server, using Apple's push notification server.

Answer (score 12):

To become an MDM vendor, you need:

1) An Apple Enterprise account

2) Contact Apple (https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit.php) and ask to be an MDM vendor.

They should enable you as an MDM vendor and you will have a "Other" tab in your "Certificates" section to send a Cert. Signing Request for MDM purposes.

Comment: This worked out of the box - they needed about 24h to activate this feature in our Account

Answer (score 6):

You do need an enterprise account, but I'm not sure whether you need to specifically request to be a vendor also. You don't need a Mac server.

As for the details of your request - are you talking about signing your 'customers' certificate signing request which is a required step now in order to be a vendor or actually setting up and running an MDM service?

Comment: Both. I want to setup and run MDM service to start with.

Comment: for CSR signing (needed to create an MDM cert for your customer) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501039/apple-mdm-vendor-csr-signing

Comment: for MDM service, you need to search through the MDM tag on stackoverflow really (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mdm) as there has been a lot of discussion around this. Obviously many people have created an MDM service but that is now part of their revenue stream, so they're quite reluctant to divulge all of their secrets!

Comment: Also see this very helpful page: http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning