# iPhone doesn't receive MDM Push notification sent by mdm server

Tags: iphone, mdm

Followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501039/apple-mdm-vendor-csr-signing/11044391#11044391) and [Softhinker](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning). Created the certificates and configuration profiles as mentioned. When the configuration profile is installed in the device, sends the Authenticate, Push Magic, and Token update to the mdm server. Till that point it is fine. But when the server tries to send a mdm push notification to the device with the mdm key and pushmagic, it is not received by the iPhone. At the server end, the push is sent successfully based on the console logs there. There is nothing to see in the console of iPhone. It doesn't show anything.

Some inputs regarding this would be helpful.

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the same steps as in [Softhinker](http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning) using openssl commands to generate the appropriate certificates. Used them on both the server (mdm server) and the client (iPhone). When the mobile config profile is installed, the server gets the details. And when the server sends the mdm push with the mdm environment to ask the device to poll for commands, that particular mdm push notification did not reach the device, how ever it shows as sent at server. Checked the mobileConfig profile created and the settings of it. Previously the mdm payload settings are as development environment. Changed it to production and tried again. Now all of it works. You might check with the production environment once, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a simple MDM platform that you can use for testing MDM commands.

It handles all the provisioning so you don't have to worry about OpenSSL.

It's called TestMDM - (http://www.testmdmapp.com)

Comment: could you please answer it, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44779249/3145189