# MDM Push Notification iOS, not received on iOS Device

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, mdm

**I know it's duplicate question** , Existing solutions are not working for me, I tried all of them almost now.

What I have done so far.

1) MDM profile is getting installed on Device.

2) I am able to receive Push notification token and push magic string on my localhost server.

**My Server and client environment is**

1) Server side, I am using Rails, Self signed SSL certificate is used, for Localhost Environment.

2) iOS 10.3 is client side, Device is connected in LAN, MDM profile installation working fine.

**References I am following.**

[To Create MDM payload, and push notification certificate](https://github.com/project-imas/mdm-server)

[To Send notification on device, Rails Gem](https://github.com/tboyko/apple_shove)

Source Code for sending notification to device is

```
    apns_p12 = File.read('my_cert.p12')
    token = '[device token string]'
    payload = { mdm: '[push magic string]' }

AppleShove.notify p12: apns_p12, device_token:token, payload:payload, expiration_date: Time.now + 60*60, priority:5
```

when above code executes, we receive the response,  notification is sent to the device and delivered, but the device never request our server to pull new configuration

**Note-**

1. I am able to download certificate from https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/
2. Once I used only .p12 of downloaded certificate from identity.apple.com.
3. Once I used  of downloaded certificate from identity.apple.com.
4. Once I used, *cat CustomerCompanyName.pem PlainKey.pem > PlainCert.pem* , with passphrase and without passphrase.

Comment: Hi. Are you saying that you can see the mdmd handling the push notification in the iOS logs? You should be able to see it making a request to your service?

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have seen your blog and TestMDM it's really nice, once notification is fired(push) from server, i get response by AppleShove(Ruby gem) => True, but device never contact our server to pull  configuration changes

Comment: please let me know, how should i process or create certificate for notification once, i got certificate from  https://identity.apple.com/pushcert/

Comment: I just followed the guide from this post: http://www.softhinker.com/in-the-news/iosmdmvendorcsrsigning. I converted the logic to C#.

Comment: Thanks, what is format of notification token, do you need to encode/decode before sending notification

Comment: without base64 encoding my token is "\xEA\u0013\xD0sa\xEFt\r\xB4\\iP\x939\xC9\xC6V\xA9\xA4*\xF3\x9By\tq\xC9c\x8C\xEB \u0017i"

Comment: could you please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/q/44886700/3145189

Comment: I posted an answer to your question. Hopefully it will help.